# Additional line in table after changing textformat

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am trying to create a table with multicolumn and a fixed width of the multicolumn inside a tikz node.

My code looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mystyle}[1]{\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (K2) {
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
        \begin{tabular}{rclr}
            \multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}}{Toptext} & text\\%
            \multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}}{\mystyle{Long Text which should be break in two lines}} &% 
        \end{tabular}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}%
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I remove the style everything looks fine. When the style is included the spacing gets weird an an additional line is added before the text included in the style.

Comment: Could you post a fully compilable code?

Comment: Why use a multicolumn here at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be very cautious when adding `\color`; in this case it is added at the wrong time. Just be sure to start paragraph mode before issuing `\color{black}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mystyle}{\leavevmode\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (K2) {%
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}%
  \begin{tabular}{rclr}
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}}{Toptext} & text\\
  \multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4.2cm}}{%
     \mystyle Long Text which should be break in two lines} &
  \end{tabular}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that you don't need to define `\mystyle` with an argument (and you need no braces either). Be also careful with end-of-lines.

There's also no reason for resetting `\tabcolsep`, because the node's content is typeset in a group.

[image]